# POIs selection from a MBTile file with osm-bright style

Tags: style, point-of-interest

I'm new to GiS and I'm missing basis. The idea is to self-host a dynamic map for users to select places like restaurants, shops, street addresses, etc.

So, here is what I did:

1. I generated the `belgium.mbtiles` files using [Planetiler](https://github.com/onthegomap/planetiler/blob/main/README.md).
2. Served the file, some Noto fonts, and a sprite from [osm-bright-gl-style](https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style) through the Martin Server
3. Then loaded the Belgium map using `MapLibre` and took the layers definition straight from the [osm-bright-gl-style](https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style). You can take a look at the [style.json here](https://file.io/iGLxNtQdNhRg)

#### Result

I can see icons that I'd call POIs.

#### Question

I can probably detect clicks and manage POI selection without any additional layer source, so I'm wondering what's the point of GeoJSON aside from adding a layer of geometric shape like markers on top of a map ...cause icons already exist here. I don't know if I'm
doing the right thing for what I want to achieve.

[image: brussels zoomed out]
[image: brussels zoomed in]

#### Problem

When I zoom in a lot, I get some errors because the map is requesting some icons from the `osm-bright-style-gl` that are not present [in the openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style repo](https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style/tree/master/icons):

```sh
Image "parking_11" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event.
```

If I zoom even more up to zoom level 15, I get HTTP errors cause the tiles are not found on the Martin server:

```sh
AJAXError: Not Found (404): http://0.0.0.0:3000/belgium/15/16779/10992
```

#### Question

Do you know where I could find the full version of the `osm-bright-gl-style` or maybe I'm doing something wrong elsewhere what do you think?

Comment: it an issue https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style/issues/47